# Mockito InvalidUseOfMatchersException when using matchers

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, matcher

New to Mockito - any ideas why this is giving me an InvalidUseOfMatchers exception?  I'm using matchers for every argument to the method in my call to Mockito.verify().  verify is operating on an interface method, and I have gotten it to work with other methods on the same interface with similar signatures, so I think I must be missing something obvious.

For background, here are a couple stripped down application classes that participate in the test:

```
public class QueueEntry {
   private String _id;

   public QueueEntry(String theId) {
       _id = theId;
   }

   public String getId() { return _id; }
}

public interface IHandler {
   public void onError(QueueEntry arg1, String arg2, String arg3);
}
```

...I'm setting up a mock for IHandler, which is a dependency of the class under test, and want to verify that the 'onError' method is called with specific arguments using Mockito matchers.  Here is a custom matcher that I have for the QueueEntry argument (arg1 in the above interface definition):

```
class EntryMatcher extends BaseMatcher<QueueEntry> {
    private QueueEntry _entry = null;
    public EntryMatcher(QueueEntry theEntry) {
        _entry = theEntry;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("Queue entry id of <" + _entry.getId() + ">");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object item) {
        QueueEntry theEntry = (QueueEntry)item;
        return theEntry.getId().equals(_entry.getId());
    }
}
```

...I'm creating the mock like this:

```
IHandler theHandler = Mockito.mock(IHandler.class);
```

...then instantiating the custom matcher like so:

```
EntryMatcher matchesEntry = new EntryMatcher( anEntryInstance );
```

...and this is where I get the exception

```
Mockito.verify(theHandler).onError( Mockito.argThat( matchesEntry ),
                                    Mockito.eq( anObject.aMethodReturningAString() ),
                                    Mockito.eq( "Job failed" ) );
```

...and here is the exception trace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:  Invalid use of argument matchers! 0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at unit.be.publishing.TestCases.testCase(TestCases.java:183)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String"); When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers. For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

Comment: You might want to consider putting together an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Jeffrey in progress...

Comment: Struggling with the same problem, seems like argThat doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: @Hoobajoob did you managed to find a solution to your problem?